# How to render SpreadsheetML in Excel, given only the Sheet1.xml

Tags: xml, excel, openxml, worksheet

I have a corrupted workbook in XLSX format, but the Sheet1.xml file inside the zip archive (xl\worksheets\Sheet1.xml) appears to be intact.

Is there a way to render this inside Excel?

I did think of creating a new workbook, and then overwriting the sheet in the zip archive, but is there a way to just open/transform/render the Sheet1.xml file, *as a worksheet*, directly in Excel? There doesn't appear to be a shared strings part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xlsx file format is a collection (archive) of xml files. There are dependences between them and MS Excel needs all of them to open the file. You cannot open only Sheet1.xml.
You need to fix the broken xml file/files.

If you have only data as you said, you can also parse Sheet1.xml and convert to CSV and open the CSV file from MS Excel.

Comment: yes, I'm aware of the usual complexity, but this file appears to be a generated file, so its complexity is quite low (the sheet equivalent of a CSV file). There doesn't appear to be any shapes, controls or shared strings. It suggests that it is entirely self-contained.

Comment: Still, MS Excel expects a file format when opens files. Also, something else, SpreadsheetML is a different file format than OpenXML (for xlsx).

Comment: OK. I was hoping for something generic, but it looks like I might just need to apply a custom transform.